# Saving Dates in MongoDB as 64-bit integers?

Tags: database, mongodb, date, datetime, mongoose

I read that MongoDB stores dates natively as a 64 bit integer. I just did the following (using mongoose in nodejs):

```
MyModel.updateMany({}, { datePublished: new Date("2021-01-01") }).then(
    function (result) {
      res.json(result);
    }
);
```

And the result looks like this:

```
{
   ...
   "datePublished": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

...doesn't seem to be a 64 bit integer? Or is this correct, and MongoDB shows me something different here (different to the way it internally stores it)?

Comment: Internally dates are stored as 64-bit integer. What you see is usually defined by your client. Typically it `"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"`, `ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")` or similar - maybe even converted to local time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MongoDB Docs:

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds >since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a representable date >range of about 290 million years into the past and future.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-document-bson-type-date

The dates are stored as an epoch timestamp but is returned as a date object which can be converted into a string if required

Comment: so what I'm doing is correct, and the dates are stored as integers & just returned to me as strings?

Comment: It should be returned as type `\x09` from https://bsonspec.org/spec.html.  The node.js driver will likely convert that to a `Date`, and it is only converted to string/prettified when converted to JSON, logged or outputted to a text-based stream.

Comment: Thanks a ton to the both of you!